# how can I access params by name of variable passed

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to access a parameter that was passed into a method by the variable name of the parameter?

```
btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SortedList<int, string> paygrades = new SortedList<int, string>();
    populatePaygrades(paygrades, sqlconnection);
    doStuffWithLists(paygrades);
}

protected void doStuffWithLists(params SortedList<int,string>[] lists)
{
 doStuffWithSubList(lists.paygrades) //??? how can I access it similar to this?
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance you may be able to provide.

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Try describing what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @codesparkle I'm trying to access the list "paygrades" by name rather than by index **by variable name

Comment: if you're passing just one single parameter to `doStuffWithLists` you can omit the `params` keyword and access `lists` with `doStuffWithSubList(lists)` ? is this what you want ?

Comment: why you using `params`? Cant you just pass paygrades?

Comment: `params` doesn't compile in this context anyway.

Comment: The reason I'm not just passing paygrades is because I'm passing 10-20 lists through the params object. params does compile in that context, I have it in working code right now. I'm trying to simplify the process of calling each list individually rather than having to loop through the whole set

Comment: Then you can extend the list class to give each single list a name field and search by name in `doStuffWithLists`

Comment: @Gabber how would I go about doing that properly? Thanks for your help

Comment: @wes At what point are you passing more than one list into doStuffWithLists? Your example only shows one list being passed. 
In which case lists[0] == paygrades
if you are doing doStuffWithLists(paygrades, someOther, aThird) and you always pass them to doStuffWithLists in the same order, you could, in doStuffWithLists access them as lists[0], lists[1], lists[2].

Comment: @Mr.Mindor it's a simplified example where I'm only showing the relevant pieces of the puzzle to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible, the `paygrades` name is local in the `btn_click` function. Unless the `SortedList` doesn't contain a field called paygrades (and I assure you it doesn't), you won't accomplish anything.

If you want to access the sublist by name you can extend the SortedList adding a name field and searching the first one by name.

Extending SortedList:

```
class MySortedList: SortedList {
    private string name;
    public string Name{
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name=value; }
    }

    //you then need to wrap all the constructors you need from SortedList
}
```

Using this in your code

```
protected void doStuffWithLists(params MySortedList<int,string>[] lists){
    foreach(MySortedList l in lists){
        if(l.Name == "paygrades")
             doStuffWithSubList(l);
}
```

Comment: How would I go about extending the sortedList to contain a name field so that I may access it by name? This is by far the closest answer

Comment: @wes are you calling doStuffWithLists from more than one place in your program?

Comment: @Mr.Mindor I'm not currently calling it in more than one location. Mainly, I'm using it to separate code.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid C#, perhaps it's Java?  The question seems to indicate that C# is desired.

Comment: It was java before, but I'm seasoned in java and c#, so it all made sense. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot. The name of the variable passed to your method is not available within the method.

**Edit:** based on your comments elsewhere, I clearly had the wrong impression of what you were trying to do. 
Instead of augmenting the SortedList with a name, you could pass a dictionary.

```
    public void CallsDoStuffWithLists()
    {
        SortedList<int, string> theFirstList = new SortedList<int, string>();
        SortedList<int, string> aSecondList = new SortedList<int, string>();
        SortedList<int, string> thirdList = new SortedList<int, string>();
        SortedList<int, string> theLastList = new SortedList<int, string>();

        PopulateTheFirstList(theFirstList);
        PopulateTheSecondList(aSecondList);
        //etc
        // call do stuff with lists.
        DoStuffWithLists(new Dictionary<string, SortedList<int, string>>{{"theFirstList", theFirstList}, {"aSecondList",aSecondList}, {"thirdList", thirdList}, {"theLastList", theLastList}});
     }

    public void DoStuffWithLists(Dictionary<string, SortedList<int,string>> lists)
    {
        // does not loop through all, 
        // does not throw exceptions..
        // if there is a list that was misnamed, it will not be handled.
        SortedList<int, string> temp;
        if(lists.TryGetValue("theFirstList", out temp)) DoStuffWithSubList(temp);
        if(lists.TryGetValue("aSecondList", out temp)) DoStuffWithSubList(temp);



        // loops through each and acts on them accordingly.
        // if DoStuffWithLists is 
        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            //or use switch statement.
            if(list.Key == "theFirstList")
            {
                DoStuffWithSubList(list.Value);
            }
            else if(list.Key == "aSecondList")
            {
                DoOtherStuffWithSublist(list.Value);
            }
            //etc...
            else
            {
                //we got an unexpected list, what do we do with it?
            }
        }
```

**On a side note:** Although I've shown you how you can do what you want, that doesn't mean it is a good idea. In this case it seems you are adding complexity without any gain. You have much more complex and error prone code, and though you are separating the data retrieval from the data processing per list, you are combining the dataprocessing for all the lists.

Have you considered having DoStuffWithLists actually do the data retreival also? far less error prone, No need to match up names.

```
btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                           
{                           

    DoStuffWithLists();                           
}    
public void DoStuffWithLists()
{
    //this is far simpler and less error prone.
    SortedList<int, string> theFirstList = new SortedList<int, string>();
    PopulateTheFirstList(theFirstList);
    DoStuffWithSubList(theFirstList);

    SortedList<int, string> aSecondList = new SortedList<int, string>();
    PopulateTheSecondList(aSecondList);
    DoOtherStuffWithSublist(aSecondList);

}
```

Or better still having a method for handling each List completely and call that instead...

```
btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)                           
{   
    //this is simpler yet, separates the concerns of each type of list.                        
    HandlePayGrade();                  
    HandleSecondList();
    HandleThirdList();
}   
public void HandlePayGrade()
{
    // you are still separating your data access and processing concerns here.
    SortedList<int, string> paygrades = new SortedList<int, string>();                               
    populatePaygrades(paygrades, sqlconnection);       
    DoStuffWithPaygrades(paygrades);
}
```

**Edit: Original answer below--** 
Based on how you have stuff named (lists), it looks as though you are expecting all the lists passed into doStuffWithLists to be handled simultaneously. This is not the case, each time it is called it deals with the one list that was passed.

An Example using integers...

```
//Double an int is invoked 3 times, each time dealing with one integer.
public int DoubleAnInt(int x)
{
    return x+x;   
}

public void CallsDoubleAnInt()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = DoubleAnInt(a);

    int c = DoubleAnInt(b);
    int d = DoubleAnInt(c);
}
```

Also Looks like you are trying to get doStuffWithLists to behave differently depending on where it was called from. In this case you just want different methods.

```
protected void doStuffWithPaygradeLists(SortedList<int,string> list)
{
    ...
}

protected void doStuffWithSomeOtherLists(SortedList<int,string> list)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Your updated answer is very good. What I ended up doing is actually setting up an enum loosely based on the answers provided to remove the complexity of using strings. Thanks for your help +1.